# SVG Glyphs with Huge Dimensions

Tags: fonts, svg, glyphs

I am using some [third-party SVG music fonts](https://github.com/OpenLilyPondFonts/haydn.git) for an application. The single glyphs of these fonts, are by default very huge in size. I was wondering what the reason for this could be. I can think of, this allows to do more fine-tuning work while designing the fonts, and since they are of course scalable, they should be down-scaled as needed when I want to actually use them. Is this true, or are there some other points to consider?

Comment: Fonts are typically designed on large canvases because some font formats only support integer values.

Comment: And hence should always be scaled as needed for use?

Comment: No, more likely the font was designed as a generic font first, hence the size. Truetypes and opentypes are always scaled.